# Multer file upload not working with node server but with express server

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, multer

I have a server file which is being used in uploading files and to implement chat in main page. The problem is that multer file upload is not working with `http.listen()` but with `app.listen()` whereas the other package, socket.io, is only working with `http.listen()`, so at a time I can only have either chat or file upload working.

Here's the useful code:

```
var express = require("express");
var fs = require('fs');
var multer  = require('multer');
var app =  express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);

app.set("view engine","ejs");

var fileinfo = [];
var dir = __dirname +"\\files\\";

//storage for multer with  destination and filename
some code here

var upload = multer({storage: storage}).array('newfile',50);

//home page checks for files in the files folder and passes file info to home.ejs
code here.route for home page 


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log("message recieved" + msg);
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});

// route to download files
app.get('/download/:namefile', function(req, res){
    //  console.log("hey man" + req.params.namefile);
    var file = dir + req.params.namefile;
    // var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    // filestream.pipe(res);
    res.download(file);
});

//route to upload files. It used upload method defined above to upload the files via multer
app.post("/uploadfile",function(req,res){
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('Error Occured ' + err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(req.files);
        res.end('Your Files Uploaded');
    })
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Currently this is working for chat.

Comment: did you try? [socket.io with express](https://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4)

Comment: Code works, both services work in my setup.

Comment: @HaroonKhan yes i tried that too. with that it's not working for both upload and chat